# Unable to get facebook videos meta data on live server

Tags: php, facebook, web-scraping, metadata, api-linkpreview

So I've been using this [package](https://packagist.org/packages/layered/page-meta) for extracting meta-data of various web URLs. I've been able to extract metadata successfully for every site except Facebook. Some of the Facebook URLs are returning Login page metadata when scraped. For an instance, I'm able to get all the information such as secure_url, thumbnails, cover-images, URLs of this [link](https://www.facebook.com/110078947973764/videos/238321518352810/) but when I go for this [Link](https://fb.watch/8JtJD305i_/). It just returns the metadata of a login page.

Also, I've been able to parse all the Facebook-related URLs on local successfully, but when it comes to live server, packages return facebook login metadata and not of the actual page.

Below are my questions

1. Is there any other PHP composer packages that can extract/parse/scrape information of Facebook URLs?
2. Do I need to do anything extra when it comes to live server?
3. Is there anything I'm doing wrong
4. Do you have any other better way of scraping/parsing/extracting Facebook-related URLs?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So they do things like require login to make it harder.

Comment: But I am able to scrap them in localhost

Comment: Facebook still doesn't allow you to do it. They probably figure it out and start blocking you there too soon.